# Google Viewer url

Tags: php, session

**Task:** To view the pdf in google viewer and the user cannot see the original pdf path/url in view source. So i decide to pass the pdf url in php by using session

**viewer.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url']= 'http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf';
?>
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://sitename.com/pdf.php&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

**pdf.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SESSION['url']);
?>
```

I check in pdf.php session variable using var_dump, it return http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf correctly, but not work in google viewer.

But when i put the url directly yo readfile, it works. 
eg

```
readfile('http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf');
```

or

```
$a = 'http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf';
readfile($a);
```

Please help me, why session variable not work in readfile

*sorry, for my english*

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say it is wrong cookie (session) context.
When you set $_SESSION, your browser is client `A`. Then you open iframe and ask `http://docs.google.com/viewer?` to download your `pdf.php` by Google as client `B` (check your http server log, there are two IPs) and put result as viewer application to your browser, **but you did not set cookies for client `B`**.
What you should do:
Looks like you need to set session id within iframes url using rawurlencode().

**viewer.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['url']= 'http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf';
?>
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=<?php 
    // set current session_id for feature Google GET request
    echo rawurlencode("http://sitename.com/pdf.php?PHPSESSID=".session_id()); 
  ?>&embedded=true" width="600" height="780" style="border: none;"></iframe>
```

**pdf.php**

```
<?php
session_id($_GET['PHPSESSID']); // we use $_GET, not COOKIE
session_start();
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
readfile($_SESSION['url']);
```

Comment: Thanks...but i check it soon

Answer (score 1):

session_start() itself is an wrapper for specific cookie handling for the session key. it can be defined by `session_set_save_handler()`. In short, it also modify the header.

If you use session_start() at the top of a php script that also has header() calls later in the script for a file download then you must add some form of cache control for IE to work properly.  I use header('Cache-Control: public'); immediately after the code at the top of the script with the session_start() call that verifies that I have a properly logged in user.  That allows the header() and fpassthru() calls to download a file later in the script using IE 5.5 SP2.

Comment: You need to first know that session itself is also a key from cookie. So by modifying the cookie header by session_start may have different behaviors in browsers.